# Shell and su command

Tags: bash, shell, su

Can someone please explain why when i issue:

> su
>   echo $0

it says:

> bash

when

> su -
>   echo $0

it says:

> -su

?
Am i right that in the 1-st case (just `su`) current shell spawns a new non-interactive shell while in the second case (`su -`) it just stays with the current shell?

Answer (score 2):

When you using just `su` you inheriting environment of user that running `su`. In contrast, when you using `su -` (it is shortcut for `-login` option of `su`) it switching you "completely" to root's account and setting up environment in the same way as if it happen if you login directly to root

Answer (score 1):

Alex's answer is correct, but he hasn't really explained what you're seeing. When you run `su -` it's importing the environment of the user you are switching to (root in this case). The last command you ran as root must have been `su`.